# WPF MVVM global cache system

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a TreeView on the left that is displaying directories. If you select a directory, the contents of that directory (which are directories and files) are displayed on the right in a ListView where each file is displayed with its own icon based on it's file extension. Right now I'm using this to cache the icons:

```
Dictionary<string, BitmapImage> dict = new Dictionary<string, BitmapImage>();
```

where the index is the file extension. This improves performance a lot, however, for each instance it's creating a new dictionary, so for each directory the user clicks, a new "cache system" is created. When a user goes to C:\Windows\System32, the first time the app is running, this may take like 5 seconds to load. I was wondering if there's a global way to do this, some global dictionary that I can already start filling upon application start in some other thread and that is accessible in my viewmodels and models, so without creating an instance of the dictionary each time.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, but why don't you just make the dictionary `static` and only add new extensions on demand?

Comment: OMG, thanks Heinzi, I just did that, works like a charm!!! Cheers!!!